# adding ajax to custom theme for certain form element?

Tags: theming, forms, ajax

How do you add ajax to custom theme for certain form element?

I would like to redesign element type radios. I created function to output custom html but now i am stuck with ajax - the javascript for this element is not added.

How do i do that?

Comment: Could you add more information how you try to add ajax ?

Comment: i just tried to add class 'ajax-processed', but looking deeper in the code, i found out that this class is the result of settings, not initator.

Comment: I have added '#ajax' attribute to the element in form, if this was your question.